# Groupby and Weighted Variance

Tags: pandas

For the below test dataset, I want to groupby "name" and obtained the weighed variance for each group. I tried the below code, but got all nan

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import DescrStatsW
import pandas as pd


data = {
        
"name": ['dick', 'sam', 'sam', 'sam','susan', 'susan', 'john', 'john', 'john'],
"last_name": ['lim', 'tan', 'tan', 'lim', 'wee', 'lim', 'low', 'tan', 'tan'],
"id": ['S','F', 'S','F', 'F', 'S', 'S','F', 'F',],
"loc": ['E','W', 'N','S', 'N', 'S', 'E','N', 'N'],
"sex": ['M','M', 'F','F', 'F','F', 'M','F', np.nan],
"age": [9999,20, 20,20, 20, 20, 20,40, np.nan],
'wt': [90, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

wm =lambda x: DescrStatsW(df["age"], weights=df["wt"], ddof=0).var

df_gpby = df.groupby(["name"], dropna=True).agg({"age": wm}).reset_index()

print(df_gpby)
```

**Desired Output**

```
| name     | age            |
| -------- | -------------- |
|dick      | nan            |
|john      | 44.72          |
|sam       | 0.00           |
|susan     | 0.00           |
```

**Formula for Weighted Variance**

[https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=7a2c69c6327a5bedJmltdHM9MTcwNTk2ODAwMCZpZ3VpZD0wNTA5NDI1ZS1kMWNhLTY0NjAtM2NkNC01MTc5ZDA4ZjY1YzQmaW5zaWQ9NTQ3OQ&ptn=3&ver=2&hsh=3&fclid=0509425e-d1ca-6460-3cd4-5179d08f65c4&psq=forumla+for+weighted+variance&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuaXRsLm5pc3QuZ292L2Rpdjg5OC9zb2Z0d2FyZS9kYXRhcGxvdC9yZWZtYW4yL2NoMi93ZWlnaHZhci5wZGYjOn46dGV4dD1UaGUlMjBmb3JtdWxhJTIwZm9yJTIwdGhlJTIwdmFyaWFuY2UlMjBpcyUzQSUyMCUyOEVRJTIwMi0yMyUyOSx3ZWlnaHRzJTJDJTIwYW5keHdpcyUyMHRoZSUyMHdlaWdodGVkJTIwbWVhbiUyMG9mJTIwdGhlJTIwb2JzZXJ2YXRpb25zLg&ntb=1]

Comment: Can you show the expected output? I don't understand what do you mean by weight variance

Comment: @PTQuoc: Have edited to show the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your solution with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and output is different:

```
print (DescrStatsW(df.loc[df['name'].eq('dick'), "age"], weights=df.loc[df['name'].eq('dick'),"wt"], ddof=0).var)
0.0

print (DescrStatsW(df.loc[df['name'].eq('john'), "age"], weights=df.loc[df['name'].eq('john'),"wt"], ddof=0).var)
nan
```

---

```
wm =lambda x: DescrStatsW(x["age"], weights=x["wt"], ddof=0).var

df_gpby = df.groupby(["name"], dropna=True).apply(wm).reset_index(name='age')

print(df_gpby) 
    name  age
0   dick  0.0
1   john  NaN
2    sam  0.0
3  susan  0.0
```

If remove missing values first:

```
df = df.dropna()
print (DescrStatsW(df.loc[df['name'].eq('dick'), "age"], weights=df.loc[df['name'].eq('dick'),"wt"], ddof=0).var)
0.0

print (DescrStatsW(df.loc[df['name'].eq('john'), "age"], weights=df.loc[df['name'].eq('john'),"wt"], ddof=0).var)
100.0
```

---

```
wm =lambda x: DescrStatsW(x["age"], weights=x["wt"], ddof=0).var

df_gpby = df.dropna().groupby(["name"], dropna=True).apply(wm).reset_index(name='age')

print(df_gpby) 
    name    age
0   dick    0.0
1   john  100.0
2    sam    0.0
3  susan    0.0
```

If need set `NaN`s for groups with length `1` is possible change your lambda function:

```
wm =lambda x: DescrStatsW(x["age"], weights=x["wt"], ddof=0).var if len(x) > 1 else np.nan

df_gpby = df.dropna().groupby(["name"], dropna=True).apply(wm).reset_index(name='age')

print(df_gpby) 
    name    age
0   dick    NaN
1   john  100.0
2    sam    0.0
3  susan    0.0
```